# responsive datatable doesn't fit on table expand

Tags: html, css, datatables, response

I am trying to make my dataTable responsive. I am using HTML5 and I have added this in css:

```
#dataTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid #bbb
}
#dataTable td,th {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    table {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when columns are expanded rows are going out of the corners of the table and is not responsive. Instead when minimizing browser and table is smaller it is responsive. Just when expand the table. What is wrong?

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?need more css

Comment: that's all my css the other css is of dataTables.bootstrap.css do you need it?

Comment: I think when its minimizied <=900px its responsive otherwise is not. how to improve this code? @Sai Ram Sudheer

Comment: Looking at the  dataTables.bootstrap.css.wierd as they should perfectly work for desktop resolutions as well..will post answer if i get it

Comment: take a look at this http://demo.onokumus.com/metis/table.html  I am using this template and if you minimize it you will see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following class in your CSS

```
#dataTable_wrapper
{
 overflow:auto;
}
```